# Why does my foreach loop not get executed?

Tags: php, html, sql, session, foreach

I made a login form. The form works and after the user inputs the right email and password, access is granted. There is an issue. 
I use a foreach loop to test all results (should be one account).

```
foreach ($result as $outp) {
                        $role = $outp->role; 
                        $name= $outp->name; 
                        $surname= $outp->surname; 
                        $_SESSION["name"] = $name; 
                        $_SESSION["surname"] = $surname; 
                        $_SESSION["role"] = $role;
                        if($_SESSION["role"] == 'Admin') {
                            header("location:index.php");  
                        } else 
                        if($_SESSION["role"] == 'User') {
                            header("location:../index.php");  
                        } else {
                            header("location:login.php");  
                        }
                    }
```

This code is supposed to check for the account role, and determine which page it can go to.
The issue is that everything inside of the foreach loop does not get executed.

Here you see the full code including the foreach loop (only php):

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
        { 
            if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
            {  
                $message = '<label>Some fields are still empty</label>';  
            }  
            else   
            {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = :email AND password= :password";  
                $statement = $con->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                    array(  
                        'email'     =>     htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]),  
                        'password'     =>     htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"])  
                    )  
                );  




                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  

                    $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["password"]; 
                    $username = $_SESSION["email"];
                    $query = "SELECT role, name, surname FROM account WHERE email = :email";

                    $stm = $con->prepare($query);
                    $stm->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $stm->execute();
                    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                    foreach ($result as $pers) {
                        $rol = $pers->rol; 
                        $voornaam = $pers->voornaam; 
                        $achternaam = $pers->achternaam; 
                        $_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam; 
                        $_SESSION["achternaam"] = $achternaam; 
                        $_SESSION["rol"] = $rol;
                        if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Admin') {
                            header("location:index.php");  
                        } else 
                        if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Gebruiker') {
                            header("location:../index.php");  
                        } else {
                            header("location:login.php");  
                        }
                    } 

                }  
                else  
                {  
                   $message = '<label>Wrong input</label>';  
                }  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Maybe `$result` is false or contains no rows?

Comment: it contains rows

Comment: why dont you try printing the value of $result to a log or console before entering the loop.  Something is wrong about the values it contains compared to what you are expecting it to contain.

Comment: did u try printing $count

Comment: the reason why it happens is probably that your query fails to return results. Try to print_r what is inside $result and you will see. BTW using preparede statements there is no need for htmlspecialchars or other sanitizations. Remove it and see if the result changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$email is used in SQL but no where declared or assigned.

```
if($count > 0)  
                    {  

                        $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"]; 
                        $email = $_SESSION["email"];
                        $query = "SELECT role, name, surname FROM account WHERE email = :email";

                        $stm = $con->prepare($query);
                        $stm->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                        $stm->execute();
                        $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                        foreach ($result as $pers) {
                            $rol = $pers->rol; 
                            $voornaam = $pers->voornaam; 
                            $achternaam = $pers->achternaam; 
                            $_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam; 
                            $_SESSION["achternaam"] = $achternaam; 
                            $_SESSION["rol"] = $rol;
                            if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Admin') {
                                header("location:index.php");  
                            } else 
                            if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Gebruiker') {
                                header("location:../index.php");  
                            } else {
                                header("location:login.php");  
                            }
                        } 

                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                       $message = '<label>Wrong input</label>';  
                    }  
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong here in your code.. why assign posted password value to email?

```
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["password"]; 
$username = $_SESSION["email"];
```